# Behaviour of List<String> when using in return statement in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

```
class A
{
    public static List<String> a = new List<string>();

    public static List<String> test()
    {
        A.a.Add("20");
        A.a.Add("30");
        A.a.Add("40");
        return a.Sort();

    }
}
```

Throws up a compile error :

> Cannot implicitly convert void to System.Collections.Generic.List.

But, If I write a method to get the `List<String>` value (since it is the static member variable) everything should work fine. But, I am unaware why despite my method returning a `List<String>` value, why does the compiler throw this error ?

Comment: Wow! my method is not returning a List<String> value. Since, I used sort() which returns the void value, the error is shown. Wonderful.. A lot to learn ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But, I am unaware why despite of my method returning a List value, why does the compiler throw this error ?

The [`List<T>.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) method *doesn't* return a `List<T>`. It's a `void` method - it sorts the list in place. You need:

```
a.Sort();
return a;
```

Basically a method with a `void` return type can *only* be used as a standalone statement. You can't use it as an expression to return, or as a method argument etc.

Comment: Does it mean that we need not assign a = a.Sort() to move the sorted elements to a ? Is it automatically sorted (I am new to C#. I guess it should be something like pass by reference where the list is itself sorted ?)

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: You can't use assignment with `List<T>.Sort()`, for exactly the same reason - *it doesn't return anything*. The list is sorted "in place". It's not really pass by reference, but you do need to understand reference types. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html

Comment: Actually I need to get the distinct value from the list. Can I just found out that distinct() method can be used like a.Distinct(). Is this the correct way ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: No, because that's a LINQ method and LINQ is based on *not* making changes to the underlying data sources. It seems to me you ought to slow down - learn the *basics* of C# (such as how reference types work), then the core libraries like collections, *then* LINQ. Otherwise you're just going to confuse yourself.

Comment: Yes Jon.. initially started learning LINQ and yes it is quite confusing without basics. I have to start from beginning. OK. But, If I dont use a Distinct() method here, how to sort the elements then ? Why do U say that LINQ slows this coding down? I studied somewhere LINQ is a new feature in C# and is fast.. sorry if this is  silly.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: LINQ doesn't slow coding down - it greatly simplifies it - but only if you're building on a solid conceptual foundation. Trying to learn LINQ at the same time as learning the basics will be slower than learning just the basics first.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `a.Sort()` has no return value - it returns void. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx. Add a line at the bottom saying `return a;`.

Answer (score 4):

sort is void function it only sort your list and doesn`t return list<>
use below code

```
  class A
    {
    public static List<String> a = new List<string>();

    public static List<String> test()
    {
        A.a.Add("20");
        A.a.Add("30");
        A.a.Add("40");
       A.a.Sort();
         return a;
    }

}
```